# How do i delete the entire replace-as-you-type list from MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to delete most of the entries from the replace-as-you-type list in Word's AutoCorrect.  I only need a few entries and deleting all the unwanted ones one by one using the delete button provided would take a very long time.   I found a macro that backups up and restores the list.  It's here:

http://www.word.mvps.org/FAQs/Customization/ExportAutocorrect.htm

I thought I could use this to export the list to a Word doc, delete most of the entries I didn't want, then "restore" using the modified list.  But doing so only allows me to change existing entries.  I can't delete entries completely.  Deletions are just ignored.

Does anyone have a suggestion for deleting entries?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a macro.  You may want to backup your autocorrect file first.

In a blank document, go to the Developer tab and click the Visual Basic button at far left.  I just added the following code to "ThisDocument".

STEP 1:  Use a macro to create a table with all your existing autocorrect entries.

Sub getACentriesTable()

Dim z As Integer

z = Application.AutoCorrect.Entries.Count

Dim i as Integer

For i = 1 To z

```
Selection.InsertAfter Application.AutoCorrect.Entries(i).Name & vbTab & Application.AutoCorrect.Entries(i).Value & vbCr
```

Next i

Selection.ConvertToTable

End Sub

When you run the above macro getACEntriesTable, you should get a 2 column table in your document listing all your current autocorrect entries.

You can then go through the table and delete all the entries you DON'T WANT TO KEEP.

STEP 2:  Use a macro to delete ALL autocorrect entries, and then reimport only the entries from your table.

Sub resetACentries()

'DELETE all autocorrect entries

Dim z As Integer

z = Application.AutoCorrect.Entries.Count

Dim i as Integer

For i = z To 1 Step -1

```
Application.AutoCorrect.Entries(i).Delete

'NB: looping through items from end to start so index number is correct after each deletion (will only be z number of entries at very start, will decrease by 1 each loop)
```

Next i

'ADD BACK in the entries you left in the table in this document

Dim tblRow As row

For Each tblRow In Selection.Tables(1).Rows

```
Application.AutoCorrect.Entries.Add Left(tblRow.Cells(1).Range.Text, Len(tblRow.Cells(1).Range.Text) - 2), Left(tblRow.Cells(2).Range.Text, Len(tblRow.Cells(2).Range.Text) - 2)
```

'NB don't want last two hidden marker characters in table cell, just the actual text string, so length of string - 2

Next

End Sub